# Python quit unexpectedly when trying to make a simple graph

Tags: macos, python-2.7, graph, matplotlib

I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4 and Python 2.7.

I just wanted to make a scatter plot graph in python. It runs completely fine until I begin to put in the lines about graph. So when I include window = plt.figure().

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# this program will graph things on a scatter plot

def scatter(filename):
    flux_array =[]
    ratio_array = []
    with open(filename, "U") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        for row in reader: 
            flux_array.append(row[0])
            ratio_array.append(row[1])
    window = plt.figure()
    plot = window.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on = True) #sets up plot in figure\
    plot.set_title("H-aplha vs. H-alpha/H-beta")
    plot.set_xlabel("H-aplha")
    plot.set_ylabel("ratio")
    plot.scatter(flux_array,ratio_array, 10, "b")
    window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
scatter('/Users/Emily/Documents/MMO_2013/Graphs/sample.csv')
```

Here is the error I get: (sorry it is really long)
A new window pops up and that has the headline "Python has quit unexpectedly"
And in the rest of the window it says:

```
Process:         Python [23039]
Path:            /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      org.python.python
Version:         2.7.0 (2.7.0)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  Python [23034]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-06-20 16:44:34.145 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          14896 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           6
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  26 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   6
Anonymous UUID:                      9498690C-E00D-5F98-DA9B-09FF275B2770

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x96e0ea6a __pthread_kill + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x95a9cb2f pthread_kill + 101

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x95ad34ec abort + 168

3   Tcl                             0x02a9cd93 Tcl_PanicVA + 229

4   Tcl                             0x02a9cdae Tcl_Panic + 27

5   Tcl                             0x02a7324d 0x2a20000 + 340557

6   Tcl                             0x02a68626 TclStackAlloc + 60

7   Tcl                             0x02a94ddf TclResetShadowedCmdRefs + 31

8   Tcl                             0x02a2c35b Tcl_CreateCommand + 432

9   _tkagg.so                       0x029f27e0 _tkinit(_object*, _object*) + 112

10  org.python.python               0x000ca3e0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20720

11  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

12  org.python.python               0x000ca471 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20865

13  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

14  org.python.python               0x000ca471 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20865

15  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

16  org.python.python               0x00041ca2 function_call + 162

17  org.python.python               0x0000f375 PyObject_Call + 85

18  org.python.python               0x000c7d5b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10859

19  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

20  org.python.python               0x00041ca2 function_call + 162

21  org.python.python               0x0000f375 PyObject_Call + 85

22  org.python.python               0x00021c66 instancemethod_call + 422

23  org.python.python               0x0000f375 PyObject_Call + 85

24  org.python.python               0x000c435e PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 78

25  _tkinter.so                     0x00722ccc PythonCmd + 220

26  Tcl                             0x00737377 TclInvokeStringCommand + 135

27  Tcl                             0x00738fc8 TclEvalObjvInternal + 678

28  Tcl                             0x0075e4e5 TclExecuteByteCode + 2050

29  Tcl                             0x0075dc49 Tcl_ExprObj + 1115

30  Tcl                             0x0073b3fa Tcl_ExprBooleanObj + 40

31  Tcl                             0x007418ba Tcl_IfObjCmd + 210

32  Tcl                             0x00738fc8 TclEvalObjvInternal + 678

33  Tcl                             0x0073a061 EvalEx + 926

34  Tcl                             0x00739cbe Tcl_EvalEx + 50

35  Tk                              0x01006b83 Tk_BindEvent + 4036

36  Tk                              0x0100b2ea TkBindEventProc + 295

37  Tk                              0x01012460 Tk_HandleEvent + 1277

38  Tk                              0x0102ab46 TkDoConfigureNotify + 114

39  Tk                              0x0102a9c5 Tk_MakeWindowExist + 331

40  Tk                              0x0102aa63 Tk_MapWindow + 34

41  Tk                              0x0102379b ArrangePacking + 1750

42  Tcl                             0x00791309 TclServiceIdle + 61

43  Tcl                             0x0078086d Tcl_DoOneEvent + 337

44  Tk                              0x0100c5e0 Tk_UpdateObjCmd + 135

45  Tcl                             0x00738fc8 TclEvalObjvInternal + 678

46  Tcl                             0x007392fd Tcl_EvalObjv + 118

47  _tkinter.so                     0x00724738 Tkapp_Call + 216

48  org.python.python               0x000ca3e0 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20720

49  org.python.python               0x000cbc88 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27032

50  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

51  org.python.python               0x000ca471 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20865

52  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

53  org.python.python               0x000ca471 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20865

54  org.python.python               0x000cbc88 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27032

55  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

56  org.python.python               0x000caefa PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 23562

57  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

58  org.python.python               0x00041ca2 function_call + 162

59  org.python.python               0x0000f375 PyObject_Call + 85

60  org.python.python               0x000c7d5b PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10859

61  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

62  org.python.python               0x000ca471 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20865

63  org.python.python               0x000cc4ba PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2042

64  org.python.python               0x000cc647 PyEval_EvalCode + 87

65  org.python.python               0x000f24bf PyRun_StringFlags + 287

66  org.python.python               0x000f25be PyRun_SimpleStringFlags + 78

67  org.python.python               0x00109db8 Py_Main + 1512

68  org.python.python               0x00001f82 0x1000 + 3970

69  org.python.python               0x00001ea9 0x1000 + 3753

Threads 1-6 ...

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x02ad639d  ecx: 0xbfffba8c  edx: 0x96e0ea6a
  edi: 0xac6efa28  esi: 0x00000006  ebp: 0xbfffbaa8  esp: 0xbfffba8c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000206  eip: 0x96e0ea6a   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x02ad639d
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x1ff5 +org.python.python (2.7.0 - 2.7.0) <E493A842-C949-A532-656D-BC10750CCB80> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
    0x5000 -   0x142fe3 +org.python.python (2.7.0, [c] 2004-2008 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.0) <2815ECAD-BE96-97DE-C757-303EB571862B> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
  0x2d6000 -   0x2d7fff +time.so (???) <36AF5C9C-9495-3868-8A5A-4706C959F102> 
a lot more lines like this...
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
 0x1554000 -  0x1556ff5 +_csv.so (???) <A4454B5F-D112-B662-F4A5-9B2E3C630DD2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_csv.so
 0x161c000 -  0x16bdff9  multiarray.so (27.4) <3A9DA8B8-2C58-3FB0-B491-968A52101BA4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/multiarray.so
 0x16d1000 -  0x1708ffe  umath.so (27.4) <F31C1D02-F34A-36F5-847C-16CB5DC6610A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/umath.so
 0x1714000 -  0x1725ff7  _sort.so (27.4) <36D7E10C-CC33-3A4A-9717-29F165644354> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_sort.so
 0x176a000 -  0x176efff  _dotblas.so (27.4) <C457183A-71CF-39AF-BEDD-8874CB2D190C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_dotblas.so
 0x1772000 -  0x178cff0  scalarmath.so (27.4) <078B9F29-CD28-3635-BCBC-4CFC6B392BEA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/scalarmath.so
 0x1791000 -  0x1791ff5 +_weakref.so (???) <CC5A6874-5A1A-4431-FB8B-3CA18F0DDE5D> 
more lines like this...
 0x2e22000 -  0x2e23ffd  com.apple.ironwoodcore (1.1.1 - 1.1.1) <098CE576-3239-3B41-9141-A5BE6E476C84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechObjects.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictationServicesCore.framework/DictationServicesCore
0x8fe75000 - 0x8fea7e57  dyld (210.2.3) <23516BE4-29BE-350C-91C9-F36E7999F0F1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90007000 - 0x9000ffff  libcopyfile.dylib (89) <4963541B-0254-371B-B29A-B6806888949B> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
a lot more lines like this...
/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 2
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 818
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0
Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B0E, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.62f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353637334648302D4346382020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
```

I have googled this quite a bit, but there aren't any answers really.

Thanks!

Comment: can you past the whole error with out snipping?

Comment: I tried to when I initially asked the question but it is way over the character limit and this comment will only allow 500 characters or so. I could take out my code at the beginning of the message. Would that be better? I think it would only still cut out characters out of the error. Is there a certain part you'd like to see?

Comment: there is a character limit on questions?!  I am not an expert at debugging mac issues so I'm not sure what would help, but generally more is better ;)  My naive guess at what is going on is that you have  multiple version of python/libraries installed and they are clashing.  Can you sort out if this is `matplotlib` or the csv reader blowing up? (change code to make scatter plot of random data)

Comment: That could totally be it that the versions might be clashing but honestly I have no idea how to figure that out.

Comment: Also I checked and it is not the csv reading. I print out those values just fine.

Comment: Sorry I keep hitting enter. I also don't know how to sort out if it is matplotlib. I would guess it has to do with versions of python or numpy that are floating around but Im not sure how to check that out.

Comment: I would suggest removing everything and re-installing using one of the aggregated installers (ex enthought canopy).

Comment: By everything do you mean python and numpy? I just actually reinstalled a new version of python a few days ago so that one should not be the problem...

Comment: but how did you install it, and did you purge the old version first?  From what you describe you may have three (system, old install, new install) incompatible versions of python on your computer.

Comment: Yes that sounds like the correct description of what I did… how could I specify which one that the system should use?

Comment: I have almost no understanding of macs, That last comment basically exhausts my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with IDLE not knowing how to handle the windows created by matplotlib. 
What I needed to do was go to the terminal and do:

ipython -pylab

In [1]: run file.py

And that fixed it. Ipython knows how to deal with the interactivity with the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your computer is crashing as the main thread is causing problems. Check if your Python is corrupt or that your graphics and system components are working well.

Comment: Stupid question, but how would I do that?

Comment: Reinstall python or compare with another copy for Python. And for the other bit, use System Profiler or ask Apple.